# EF: How to eliminate a joi-table in the model while still respecting relationship among tables in the underline database?

Tags: entity-framework

Let's say I have a Database with 3 tables: **Keywords**, **Documents**, and **KeywordDocuments**. KeywordDocuments has only 3 columns, **KeywordDocumentID**, **KeywordID**, and **DocumentID**.

The relationship between Documents and KeywordDocuments is the same as Keywords and KeywordDocuments, i.e. one-to-many.

Watching Julie Lerman's video on EF, she said that we don't need KeywordDocuments's entity in the model. How do I eliminate that entity while making sure that in the relationship will be respected in the underline database?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the KeywordDocumentID column from the KeywordDocument table. It will then contain only the foreign key columns from the tables for which it represents a many to many relationship.

Create a new composite primary key on the KeywordDocument table which includes both the KeywordID and the DocumentID columns. This will replace the original primary key that you had on the KeywordDocumentID column - that key  would have been deleted along with the column.

A table such as this will not result in an entity being generated in the model. Rather, both of the other entities (Keyword and Document in this case) will have navigation properties based on EntityCollection. Document will have a collection of Keywords and vice verca.

Comment: Once you remove KeywordDocumentID don't forget to mark those FKs as composite primary key or your junction table will be read only.

Comment: Thanks @Ladislav Mrnka. I forgot to include the new primary key  - I have added it now.

Comment: @Scoot Munro: Can u explain a little more [...Create a new primary key for the table to include both the columns. This will replace the original one that you had on the KeywordDocumentID column....] .i.e your second pargraph

Comment: @Richard77: I have expanded a little in the question. If you were not aware that it is possible to define a primary key over multiple columns then this might have been what is causing the confusion. Experiment with creating such a key and my answer should become clearer.

Comment: So you mean, the KeywordDocument table will have 2 columns and both of them participating in the definition of the KeywordDocument's primary key?

Comment: Exactly. Let me know if you have any problems.